# Order of items in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've made a program were I want to store some values in an array. When I put a value in one of the input fields I store that in localStorage() and then I would like to add that value in an array called arr. Next time I put a value in another input field I would like to add that as the second item in my array called arr. That happens only if that input field comes after the first one in my HTML file. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this.

```js
var $ = jQuery;

var input = [];
var arr = [];

function saveInputs() {
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      input[i] = $("input:eq(" + i + ")").val();
      localStorage.setItem('"input' + i + '"',input[i]);
   }
}

$("#save").on("click", function() {
   saveInputs();
});

function loadInputs() {
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      $("input:eq(" + i + ")").val(localStorage.getItem('"input' + i + '"'));
   }
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if($("input:eq(" + i + ")").val() === "") {
         console.log("No value for input " + (i+1) + " yet.");
      } else if($("input:eq(" + i + ")").val() != "") {
         arr.push($("input:eq(" + i + ")").val());
      }
   }
   console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <br>
      <button id="save">save</button>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking.  Are you trying to keep the order of the items in the array to match the order they are in the DOM?

Comment: Create `arr` with the same size as the number of inputs you have in your page, and add content to it using the "index" of the input... ex: if is input2 then arr[2]=..., if is input5 then arr[5]=... (the variable `i` in your for loop may work)

Comment: No, I want to add the input values into the array in the same order I am using the input fields. Let's say I put a value into the second input field, save that using localStorage() and then put another value into the first input field and save that also using localStorage(). What I then want is for these values to be stored in the array in the same order I used them. That is arr['input2value','input1value'].

Comment: Thank you for your answer DIEGO CARRASCAL but I don't think that would work. I mean how can you tell your program that the first used input field will be your first value in the array at all times even though you add new ones later on.

Comment: To clarify my problem...the code I'm working with is actually for a program with football results. The results is kept in a grid with many input fields. The input fields holds the scores. Then I calculate the table using these scores. So far so good, because calculating wins, losses, goals scored etc doesn't have to use values from the input fields in any order. But I also want to include the six latest scores for each team in the table. To do that I have to know in which order the results happen. The output in the table should look something like this (W-L-L-D-W-L).